# Is there any better way to display ete2 Tree in Django template?

Tags: django, web-applications, tree, etetoolkit

I am building a WebApplication using [Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter01.html) framework. At server side I am building [ete2 tree](http://packages.python.org/ete2/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html) according to the input given by user using browser. Now my problem is I need to display this tree in client side (browser) in tree format with each node as a hyperlink (clicking on nodes displayed in tree format should invoke a function at server side passing node name as parameter, that why I mentioned it as hyperlink).

one solution came to my mind is parse the [ete2.tree](http://packages.python.org/ete2/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html) in [views](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html) function and build a string with all html tags needed which at display on browser looks like the following.

```
             + root
               + child1
                   + grandson
               + child2
```

Code to do this:
from ete2 import Tree

```
def display_view(request):
      global tree
      string = tree2str(tree)
      return render_to_response('index.html', {'string': string} )

def tree2strtr():
  global tree
  tmp = ''
  for node in tree.traverse():
    if node.name != 'NoName':
      tmp += '<a href="/process/?objectName=%s">%s</a>' % (node.name, node.name)
      tmp += '</br>'
  return tmp
```

Is there a better way to do that ? Any suggestions please..